# Flutter function return null value

Tags: flutter, dart

i have problem with my function to display current prayer time. My idea is to compare current time with list of prayer times from api. I manage to get list of prayer time from api but when doing comparison it return null. Is there any problem with my code since it return null when i print(prayerTime) ?

ApiService.dart

//List Prayer Time based on zone

```
static Future<List<PrayerTime>> getPrayerList() async {

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
var zone = sharedPreferences.getString("zone");

final response = await http.get(
  Uri.parse("$baseJakimUrl/TakwimSolat&period=today&zone=$zone"),
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  },
);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  // print(response.body);

  Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
  List<dynamic> prayer = map['prayerTime'];
  // print('prayer: ' + prayer.toString());

  return prayer.map((json) => PrayerTime.fromJson(json)).toList();
} else {
  throw Exception("Unable to  Load");
}
```

}

Home.dart

```
getNextPrayer() async {
DateTime? prayerTime;

await ApiService.getPrayerList().then((prayer) {
  prayer.map((e) {
    DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
    String d = now.toIso8601String().split('T').first;
    String asarTime = d + ' ' + e.asr.toString();
    String subuhTime = d + ' ' + e.fajr.toString();
    String zuhurTime = d + ' ' + e.dhuhr.toString();
    String maghribTime = d + ' ' + e.maghrib.toString();
    String isyakTime = d + ' ' + e.isha.toString();

    DateTime dateTimeSubuh = DateTime.parse(subuhTime);
    DateTime dateTimeZuhur = DateTime.parse(zuhurTime);
    DateTime dateTimeAsar = DateTime.parse(asarTime);
    DateTime dateTimeMaghrib = DateTime.parse(maghribTime);
    DateTime dateTimeIsyak = DateTime.parse(isyakTime);

    if (now.isAfter(dateTimeSubuh) && now.isBefore(dateTimeZuhur)) {
      prayerTime = dateTimeZuhur;
    } else if (now.isAfter(dateTimeZuhur) && now.isBefore(dateTimeAsar)) {
      prayerTime = dateTimeAsar;
    } else if (now.isAfter(dateTimeAsar) && now.isBefore(dateTimeMaghrib)) {
      prayerTime = dateTimeMaghrib;
    } else if (now.isAfter(dateTimeMaghrib) &&
        now.isBefore(dateTimeIsyak)) {
      prayerTime = dateTimeIsyak;
    } else if (now.isAfter(dateTimeIsyak) && now.isBefore(dateTimeSubuh)) {
      prayerTime = dateTimeSubuh;
    }
  }).toList();
});
print(prayerTime.toString());

return prayerTime;
```

}

any ideas?

Comment: perhaps it goes to `else`?

Comment: 1. [`Iterable.map` is lazy](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/Iterable/map.html), so it won't do *anything* until you try to access the resulting elements, but you never do anything with the result.  Using `.map` this way is inappropriate; just use a normal `for-in` loop. 2. As @JohnJoe mentioned, your don't set `prayerTime` along all code paths, but maybe that's okay if you're guaranteed that at least one path was followed on at least one iteration.